# Facebook Insights dashboard is showing wrong app version on Most recently logged events after upgrade facebook-android-sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

After I updated facebook-adroid-sdk from 3.7 to 3.20.0, Facebook Insights dashboard is showing versionCode from AndroidManifest.xml file instead the value from Settings.setAppVersion("version").

```
    AppEventsLogger logger = logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(applicationContext);
    Settings.setAppVersion("40a");
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(activityContext, activityContext.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
    logger.logPurchase(new BigDecimal(56), java.util.Currency.getInstance("USD") );
```

In version 3.7 of SDK, I can see "40a" in App Version column. After updating SDK to 3.20.0, it's showing the value in versionCode attribute from my AndroidManifest.xml file.

Let me know if any additional information would be useful and I can add it here.

Thanks in advance for any help!

I added LoggingBehavior.APP_EVENTS to see App Event logs and it looks ok. See below:

---

Flush completed

> Params: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"application_package_name":"com.xoom.android.app","advertiser_tracking_enabled":true,"advertiser_id":"c5f02567-ad97-4f40-a6c1-2be6faa97244","extinfo":"[\"a1\",\"com.xoom.android.app\",32,\"3.0\"]","application_tracking_enabled":true,"attribution":"fe900c80-b1a3-4d31-9594-b43144f80a74","event":"CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS"}}

Result: Success

```
Events JSON: [
{
     "_ui": "unknown",
     "_valueToSum": 56,
     "fb_currency": "USD",
     "_eventName": "fb_mobile_purchase",
     "_appVersion": "40a",
     "_logTime": 1416252482
   },
   {
     "_ui": "MainActivity_",
     "_eventName": "fb_mobile_activate_app",
     "_appVersion": "40a",
     "_logTime": 1416252482,
     "fb_mobile_launch_source": "Unclassified"
   }
]
```

App session info saved

Answer (score 0):

I openned a ticked in Facebook Developers Support, it looks we can't set app version in newest SDK versions. You can see discussion here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/601407286632396